# JIRA Issue/Filter Macro in Confluence generates invalid link

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, jira, confluence

The setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- JIRA Software 7.03 (on port 8080)
- Confluence 6.03 (on port 8090)
- NGINX 1.10.0 as a reverse proxy to...

  - Apache 2.4.18

The problem: Whenever I try to embed a JIRA issue into a Confluence page via the built-in JIRA Issue/Filter macro, the issue is successfully located and its status is successfully listed. However, the link from the Confluence page to the actual issue in JIRA points to localhost:8080.

As per the suggestion in [Incorrect Links in JIRA Issues Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/incorrect-links-in-jira-issues-macro-179437721.html) (cause #1), I tried enabling ProxyPreserveHost in Apache, with no discernible effect.

Question 1: Am I even digging in the right direction, or is there some other likely cause for the issue that I'm missing?

Question 2: If the issue really is likely due to a configuration mismatch between Confluence and the web server, where should I start digging, given that I'm using NGINX as a reverse proxy?

I'm very hazy on the specifics of configuring web servers. Do I need to verify my settings in both NGINX and Apache, or just Apache (NGINX is set to pass through pretty much everything non-static)? Do I just follow the instructions for [Proxying Atlassian server applications with Apache HTTP Server (mod_proxy_http)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html)? 
I haven't done this yet because I'm worried my lack of understanding will cause something to explosively decompress.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you redirect to `localhost:8080` and `8080` is JIRA's default port, I believe that you need to check following and most likely it's related to misconfiguration of the proxy:

Configuration of JIRA Base URL - Is it configured properly?
Do you have `proxyPort` and `proxyName` in the connector of server.xml?
What you are seeing when you navigate to Application Link configuration of JIRA and Confluence? Is is showing any errors?